# Disabling Exceptions in ANTLR C# target

Tags: antlr

Is it somehow possible to disable the exceptions that are thrown from ANTLR C# target? Or are they necessary that the parser can work fine?
It would be good if the exceptions can be disabled somehow, because they cause bad performance, and it's annoying to disable the antlr exceptions each time when debugging.

Comment: what is the exception you meet that makes you want to disable it? I alse use ANTLR on C# but rarely find the exceptions annoying.

Answer (score 1):

These exceptions cannot be disabled. In addition, no exceptions are thrown for valid input sequences to minimize the runtime overhead associated with the exceptions.

Not only is the C# target the fastest of *all* the ANTLR 3 targets, but under extensive long-term testing, the exceptions/handling mechanism necessary for error recovery has never appeared as a performance bottleneck.

Comment: If there are exceptions also for valid input sequences is this because we do not use the newest C# target?

Comment: @TobiasStoll It could also indicate a problem with the grammar.